# Gateaux and Frechet derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. We know then that the norm is Fréchet differentiable outside zero (actually there exists an equivalent one that is differentiable).

Now consider $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=|x|^2$.

Then its Fréchet derivative in $x_0$ is $2x_0$ so it is an element of $X$. But shouldn't the Fréchet derivative of $f$ (and also the Gateaux derivative) be an operator in $L(X,\mathbb{R})$ and so a functional?

What am I missing?

Comment: Should it be $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes of course I corrected

Comment: What do you mean by "its Fréchet derivative in $x_0$ is $2x_0$" ?

Comment: Why did **you** say that the Fréchet-derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ is $2x_0$? Note, if we are working instead with Hilbert spaces, the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ is the functional $\langle 2x_0,-\rangle \in L(X,\mathbb R)$, which corresponds with $2x_0$ via the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Yes of course in Hilbert spaces then that is the Riez representative. I wanted to treat the cae of banach spaces. So $2 x_0$ is wrong?

Comment: To answer that question, you need to answer @TheSilverDoe's question.

Comment: I mean the standard definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative

Comment: @carlos85 And can you explain how you obtained with the standard definition that the Fréchet derivative of $f$ in $x_0$ is $2x_0$ ?

Comment: No I got confused by trying to generalize it to the Banach spaces from the one I got in an Hilbert space

Comment: So it will be some functional, whose Riesz representative i ls $2x_0$ when you are in a Hilbert space. But in general I have a functional

Comment: Is it possible to compute the functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at $F(x)=\|x\|^2$ on a Hilbert space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

The [Gateau derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) is a functional $dF:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
dF(x; h)
:= \left.\frac{d}{d\lambda}F(x+\lambda h)\right|_{\lambda=0}
.
$$
Here,
$$
F(x+\lambda h)
= (x+\lambda h)^2
= \langle x+\lambda h, x+\lambda h\rangle
= \langle x, x \rangle + \langle x, \lambda h \rangle + \langle \lambda h, x\rangle + \langle \lambda h, \lambda h \rangle
\\
= \langle x, x \rangle + \lambda \langle x, h \rangle + \lambda \langle h, x\rangle + \lambda^2 \langle h, h \rangle
$$
so
$$
dF(x; h)
= \langle x, h \rangle + \langle h, x\rangle
= 2 \langle x, h \rangle
= \langle 2x, h \rangle
.
$$
The [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is a linear operator $X\to\mathbb{R}$, which in this case is $h \mapsto \langle 2x, h\rangle$ since
$$
\frac{| \|x+h\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \langle 2x, h\rangle |}{\|h\|}
= \frac{| (\langle x, x\rangle + \langle x, h\rangle + \langle h, x\rangle + \langle h,h\rangle) - \langle x,x\rangle - \langle 2x, h\rangle |}{\|h\|}
\\
= \frac{\langle h, h\rangle}{\|h\|} 
= \frac{\|h\|^2}{\|h\|} 
\to 0
$$
as $\|h\|\to0.$

Comment: Please look at the comments, in HIlbert spaces it is clear

Comment: @carlos85. Those comments were written later than my answer.

Comment: Yes you right from this perspective but the question asked when X is Banach reflexive

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(\mathbb{R}^2,||.||_1)$ where $||(x,y)||_1=|x|+|y|$.

Then you have
$$||(x,1)||_1^2=x^2+2|x|+1$$

which is obviously non differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes but I was asking outside zero